# Zero divisors in $\mathbb{Z} / b\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modular-arithmetic

How can I describe the set of all zero divisors in the ring  $\mathbb{Z} / b\mathbb{Z}$ for $b \in \mathbb{Z}, \, b\geq 2$ with a mathematical proof?

I know that the set of zero divisors just contains the equivalence classes of the numbers $x,y$ such that $x*y = b$. So now $[x], [y]$ are in the set of zero divisors. But i would like to give a mathematical prove and a with a precise description of the set

Comment: Try a couple of examples, like $b=2,3,4,5$ and $6$ first. See if you spot a pattern. Once you suspect what the pattern is, you can start working on a proof.

Comment: I know that the set of zero divisors just contains the equivalence classes of the numbers $x,y$ such that $x*y = b$. So now $[x], [y]$ are in the set of zero divisors. But i would like to give a mathematical prove and a with a precise description of the set

Comment: @Slyrack That's exactly the kind of information which we want the question post itself to contain. The downvote and close vote you have gotten is likely because that's lacking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your conjecture is wrong, I'm afraid. Consider $b=6$. Then $[4]$ is a zero divisor, because $[4][3]=[0]$, but there is no $y$ such that $4y=6$.

However, this should lead you to a more precise conjecture: indeed $4\cdot3=12=2b$, so…

---

You may want to prove that an element in $\mathbb{Z}/b\mathbb{Z}$ is either invertible or a zero-divisor (considering $[0]$ a zero-divisor). I believe you can classify the invertible elements, so to get the right conjecture for the zero-divisors. The proofs will be almost applying the definitions.

Comment: So can i describe the set of all 0 divisors as $\{[x] \in \mathbb{Z}/b\mathbb{Z} : 2 \leq x \leq b-1 \,and \,\exists c \in \mathbb{Z} \, with \,xc = db \,for \,d \in \mathbb{Z} \}$?

Comment: @Slyrack That's almost correct; it should be the set of $[x]$ such that there are $c,d\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $cx=db$ (the limitation $2\le x\le b-1$ is redundant, albeit harmless). But there's a better and simpler way to say the same thing.

Comment: Thank you. What would be that way to do it even better and simpler? I thought how I did it would be the "natural" way?

Comment: @Slyrack What about the gcd?

Comment: Is it: $\{[x]: gcd(x,b)>1\}$?

Comment: @Slyrack That's it: now try and prove it.

Comment: My attempt to prove it would be to first give my first description of the set (what I think follows directly from the definition of this ring) and then from this one I can rewrite the set with the gcd as my second description of the set was. What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

**Question:** "How can I describe the set of all zero divisors in the ring Z/bZ for b∈Z,b≥2 with a mathematical proof?"

**Answer:** Here is an approach using the Chinese Remainder Theorem where you get more information on the units: What are they?

[In $\Bbb Z/m\Bbb Z,$ if $a$ is not invertible then it is a zero divisor](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/767339/in-bbb-z-m-bbb-z-if-a-is-not-invertible-then-it-is-a-zero-divisor)